# How to change HeaderBackButton size in react native navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to change the back button size in my react native app navigation header because android is giving me a warning that the touch target size is to small (30x30px, wants it to be at least 48x48px). I'm using [reactnavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/).

I've worked out you can customize the back button in the header using `headerLeft` and the `HeaderBackButton` element like so.

```
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route, navigation}) => ({
        headerLeft: () => <HeaderBackButton style={{height: 100, width: 100}} onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)}/>
      })}>
```

However, the height and width styles have no effect. I've also tried `fontSize` with no effect. Would prefer an approach where I don't have to override `headerLeft` and reimplement all of the back button default behaviors as well just to change the size.

Comment: A Pressable with hitSlop should work. The Touchable components also have this property.

Answer (score 0):

You can style Stack's original headerLeftStyle with `headerBackTitleStyle={{fontSize: 100}}` 
If you want custom Image, use option 'headerBackImageSource'. 
If you still trying custom components, `onPress={()=> navigation.canGoBack() ? navigation.goBack() : null}` can be used.